# Can you output to D+ and D- so that Arduino Uno can be used as a USB device?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, usb, audio

My project is basically a set of 5 audio signals (analog) that get altered slightly by Arduino Uno. I convert to MIDI and would then output it to USB, so that it can be used in a program of my choice on the computer. I found a vaguely similar project online with a guide. In that project they write a serial to a MIDI out, and then plug that into a computer. I'm fairly sure I can't just use the TX and run that into the USB, that wouldn't work. So I'm looking for an alternative method.

Comment: Not directly, and not in the way you're thinking of.

Comment: Would it be better to use the digital output to connect to a midi connection, or do you need it to connect to USB?

Comment: Look into [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html).

Comment: Andy, I can not figure out what you are trying to do.  Are you going from an Arduino to a computer using the computer's USB port?  If so, why are you converting to MIDI?  Also, USB is really complex.  Most people do not realize there are many protocols inside a USB signal.   Simply having a USB device is in no way a guarantee that any given program will even work with that device.

Comment: Why not just use the Uno's USB port?  The same one used for programming.  I use them all the time to communicate measured values back to Raspberry Pis and to receive commands that trigger output pins...  And the best part is that I can WiFi into the Rpi with RDP and run the IDE to preprogram them out in the field.  In other words, why reinvent the wheel?  That USB-to-serial port works fine bidirectionally already using the Serial functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not with an Uno, no. You can only use USB Serial (CDC/ACM) through the on-board USB chip<sup>[1]</sup>.

Your best bet is probably with a Teensy 3 (or 3.1 or whatever they are up to now) which has built-in support for USB MIDI emulation.

---

<sup>1: I believe there is MIDI firmware for the USB chip on the Uno, but installing that requires a hardware programmer and then breaks the normal sketch upload.</sup>

Comment: Actually, you can come "close enough" with an Uno by using a V-USB.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If you are masochistic enough, sure. Personally I wouldn't touch it even with someone else's barge pole.

Comment: It's not without concerns, but it seems to be rather exactly what the question is asking about.

Comment: I refuse to endorse it or ever tell anyone to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in Majenko's answer, an Uno would require some non-trivial modifications before it would be usable as you want.

Some Arduino models – Leonardo and early Pro Micros – were based on ATmega32U4 chips instead of ATmega168 or ATmega328 chips.  The 32U4 has USB support built in.  The [Mouse and Keyboard](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard) libraries allow interacting with a host computer such that from the host the Arduino looks like a mouse or keyboard.

Comment: Its rather odd for you to call these "old" as they were all released *after* the Uno.  Also the Due did not use an ATmega/AVR but rather an Atmel ARM Cortex-M3 while the Zero has a Cortex M0+.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler thing would be to output the MIDI through the serial port, and then convert that into MIDI voltage levels like this:

[image: MIDI tx]

Then plug that into a suitable MIDI-to-USB adapter. However I would have thought that that extra step (converting to MIDI voltage and back again) would be unnecessary. Can't your computer read MIDI directly from serial? I mean, the Uno has a USB interface. If you send MIDI data at 31250 baud, how is the program on the PC going to know it isn't a real MIDI device on the USB port?

Comment: Operating systems expect midi-over-USB devices to identify themselves as such, not as serial or modem devices.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  Yes but a MIDI to USB adapter would surely do exactly that? I wasn't talking about putting serial straight into the computer. I mean, that's what they are made to do.

Comment: "Can't your computer read MIDI directly from serial?" does rather imply getting it to treat an everyday serial stream as midi data - something that is possible, but outside of *typical* software configuration, ie, it probably needs a custom or obscure driver, or to skip any operating system MIDI support entirely and just take the data into the application that wants to use it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Oh, OK. My suggestion of the MIDI to USB adapter would not have that issue. You are probably right about the drivers. I see such adapters are available on eBay for around $US 7 to $15.

Comment: Yes, something that's USB information presents itself as a MIDI device should work for the host meaning the challenge is electrical.  While something that presents as a serial device (and has a TTL inteface) is Arduino-friendly electrically, but would require atypical host drivers or software to be treated as a source of midi data.